# Mostrar un usuario en concreto de la tabla USER a través de su rol en symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

Me gustaria comentaros un problema que tengo en [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) a ver si me podeis ayudar
Tengo una tabla `USER` donde se almacenan los distintos tipos de usuarios, cada uno con su correspondiente `ROL (ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_PROFE, ROLE_ALUMNO)`
Intento realizar un `SELECT` en [doctrine](/questions/tagged/doctrine) para que solo aparezcan aquellos que tengan el `ROLE_PROFE`,

```
public function ProfesoresTotal($rol)
{
return $this->createQueryBuilder(‘u’)
->select(‘u’)
->where(‘u.roles = :rol’)
->setParameter(‘rol’,$rol)
->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

En la variable $rol que paso por parametro ya le hecho de todo e usado string normales, e usado json_encode y json_decode sin resultado, imagino que en $rol debe de ser de tipo json o contenerlo y ya no se que hacer
En mi bdd hecha en [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) la tabla roles guarda el rol asi: [“ROLE_PROFE”]

Mi entidad User

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=”App\Repository\UserRepository”)
* @UniqueEntity(fields={“email”}, message=”There is already an account with this email”)
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
* @ORM\Id()
* @ORM\GeneratedValue()
* @ORM\Column(type=”integer”)
*/
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type=”string”, length=180, unique=true)
*/
private $email;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type=”json”)
*/
private $roles = [];

/**
* @var string The hashed password
* @ORM\Column(type=”string”)
*/
private $password;

/**
* @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
*
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=”Cursos”, inversedBy=”user”)
* @ORM\JoinTable(name=”cursos_has_user”,
* joinColumns={
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name=”user_id”, referencedColumnName=”id”)
* },
* inverseJoinColumns={
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name=”cursos_idCurso”, referencedColumnName=”idCurso”)
* }
* )
*/
private $cursoscurso;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type=”string”, length=255)
*/
private $name;

/**
* Constructor
*/
public function __construct()
{
$this->cursoscurso = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
return $this->id;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
$this->email = $email;

return $this;
}

/**
* A visual identifier that represents this user.
*
* @see UserInterface
*/
public function getUsername(): string
{
return (string) $this->email;
}

/**
* @see UserInterface
*/
public function getRoles(): array
{
$roles = $this->roles;
// guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
$roles[] = ‘ROLE_ALUMNO’;

return array_unique($roles);
}

public function setRoles(array $roles): self
{
$this->roles = $roles;

return $this;
}

/**
* @see UserInterface
*/
public function getPassword(): string
{
return (string) $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
$this->password = $password;

return $this;
}

/**
* @see UserInterface
*/
public function getSalt()
{
// not needed when using the “bcrypt” algorithm in security.yaml
}

/**
* @see UserInterface
*/
public function eraseCredentials()
{
// If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
// $this->plainPassword = null;
}

/**
* @return Collection|Cursos[]
*/
public function getCursoscurso(): Collection
{
return $this->cursoscurso;
}

public function addCursoscurso(Cursos $cursoscurso): self
{
if (!$this->cursoscurso->contains($cursoscurso)) {
$this->cursoscurso[] = $cursoscurso;
}

return $this;
}

public function removeCursoscurso(Cursos $cursoscurso): self
{
if ($this->cursoscurso->contains($cursoscurso)) {
$this->cursoscurso->removeElement($cursoscurso);
}

return $this;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
$this->name = $name;

return $this;
}

public function __toString(){
return $this->name;
}
}
```

El resultado final es que no muestra nada y ya no se que hacer
¿Me podrian ayudar?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: El rol lo guardas en la tabla usuario en un tabla intermedia de rol_usuario?

Comment: En la misma tabla usuario (Perdona por la tardanza)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné

Lo realicé con un simple LIKE

```
 return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        "SELECT u FROM App\Entity\User u WHERE u.roles LIKE '%ROLE_PROFE%'"
    )
    ->getResult();
```